# Confusion in understanding horisontal composition of natural transformations

Tags: functor, category-theory

I'm currently reading Category Theory for Programmers by Bartosz Milewski. In chapter about natural transformation i found a following paragraph:

> Let’s focus on two objects of  — categories  and . There is
>   a set of natural transformations that go between functors that connect
>    to . These natural transformations are our new arrows from  to
>   . By the same token, there are natural transformations going between
>   functors that connect  to , which we can treat as new arrows going
>   from  to . Horizontal composition is the composition of these
>   arrows.

Could someone explain how did natural trasformation between functors that connect categories C and D suddenly became arrows connecting C and D, which would make it a functor again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It so happens that Cat has more structure than the obvious one: a category with categories as objects and functors as morphisms. There is a second layer, in which we combine all natural transformations between all pairs of functors from C to D and call it a hom-set from C to D. We define composition between these hom-sets in terms of horizontal composition of natural transformations. Notice, these new hom-sets are different from old hom-sets, which are sets of functors.